# Which ellipse does the Earth's semi-major axis refer to?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) the semimajor axis of the earth is reported to nine digits of accuracy (nearest kilometer), and the eccentricity to eight. But to which ellipse exactly does that apply? Sun-at-the-focus? Sun-earth barycenter-at-the-focus? I mean, even Jupiter is "moving the sun around" by >100,000km (and I guess us as well).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the orbit of the Earth around the Sun is influenced by all the planets and every other gravitating object in the solar system.  But their gravitational influences are relatively small compared to the Sun's, and it becomes computationally unwieldily and even impossible to account for the orbital motions of more than two and at most three mutually attracted bodies.  This is called the [n-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem#Three-body_problem).

Therefore, the semi-major axis of the Earth's orbit generally is considered to be for an ellipse with focus at the barycenter of the Earth-Sun elliptical orbit.

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Solar_system_barycenter.svg), incidentally, is a diagram of the motion of the entire Solar System's barycenter (center of mass) relative to the location of the Sun in the Solar System.

[image]

Comment: The earth-moon barycenter around the earth-sun barycenter? Do you think nine digits is too much? It seems like there aren't really aren't any true ellipses at all here.

Comment: @uhoh: There are several ways to solve the 3-body problem, but Bruns and Poincare showed that they are not given by algebraic expressions or integrals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem).  To my knowledge, all the solutions require assumptions or conditions that do not exactly match up with the solar system.  All the orbits in the solar system are ellipses - the question is how eccentric each ellipse is.  The nine digits of accuracy could be from observation rather than theoretical computation.

Comment: Thanks @Ernie. So I wrote my question narrowly to avoid too much general discussion, especially about n-body solutions and approximations. That is very important for sure. However, in regard to the value for the **Earth's** semi-major axis of "149598261 km" I ask the question "... to which ellipse exactly does that apply?" It is possible that "None" is the best answer.

Comment: Maybe it might be better to say "None of the orbits in the solar system are ellipses" rather than "All"?

Comment: I'm still having difficulty with this answer. "Therefore, the semi-major axis of the Earth's orbit generally is considered to be for an ellipse with focus at the barycenter of the Earth-Sun elliptical orbit." OK that's the location of the *focus* of an ellipse, but *what ellipse?* Is it the one-body, central-force, reduced mass ellipse that would represent the Sun-Earth system? Also, I found the source of the number. The *mean value* for the semi-major axis with all other orbital elements time-dependent is given as 1.0000010178 AU in http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994A&A...282..663S

Comment: @uhoh : General relativity predicts that orbits are not exactly elliptical, so it's correct that none of the orbits are ellipses.  In the classical limit, orbits are ellipses, but their axes change with time.  The mean value you found "for the semi-major axis with all other orbital elements time-dependent" must include effects of other bodies, like the Moon, on the Earth/Sun system.  So I don't think it's a question of "which" ellipse, but rather how the Earth/Sun orbit is computed, taking into account other bodies. http://vnatsci.ltu.edu/s_schneider/astro/astrotalk2006_barycenter_moon.pdf

Comment: OK so in the same spirit, a circular orbit could be called a "straight trajectory with time-dependent direction". I think we basically agree here except that I would not say that even classically, the planets travel in elliptical orbits. The nine and eight digit values for $a$ and $\epsilon$ only represent a "snapshot" approximate best-fit to the orbit at *one moment in time*.  There is no ellipse. https://youtu.be/uAXtO5dMqEI